# How to validate React Component props when instanciating it

Tags: validation, reactjs, properties

I dynamically create a component (of type Component_B) inside another component (Component_A)

I raise an error if Component_B constructor if the prop *id* is missing.

I would like to catch an error when instantiating Component_B.

The problem is that the constructor is called only once the Component_B has been attached to the Component_A (see below).

```
class Component_A extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        this.addComponentB = this.addComponentB.bind(this);
    }


    addComponentB(data) {

        return (
            <Component_B name=data.name />
        )
    }

    renderComponentB() {
        ...
        compB = null
        try {   
            compB = this.addComponentB({'name'='hello'});

        catch(e) {
          // I would like to catch an error here, if the 'id' prop is not set for component_B
        }

        return (
            compB
        )

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.renderComponentB}</div>
        )
    }
}    



class Component_B extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        // Solution 1
        if(!props.id){
            console.debug('if not id')
            throw 'Cant create a Component_B with no ID!';
        }
    }

    render() {
        return ....
    }
}
```

I also try with propTypes, but it doesn't work either:

```
// Solution 2
Component_B.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Comment: This looks very hacky to me. Is there a reason why rendering Component_B in Component_A like this? Why can't you just render  Component_B in the render method of Component_A and pass the props into it?

Comment: If you are controlling the props to pass into Component_B in the `addComponentB` function, why can't you check for id there?

Comment: Thanks @ChaseDeAnda for your comment. Indeed I would like to do this check inside the ComponentB, so that its impossible to instantiate it if the condition is not validated.

Comment: React doesn't work that way, the component itself shouldn't determine whether or not it gets rendered. The Parent Component should handle the conditional rendering of the component in the render method.

Answer (score 0):

You can just manually check all those props I guess. For example, this is how I did:

```
VALID_BUTTON_ATTRS: [
    'autofocus',
    'autocomplete',
    'disabled',
    'form',
    'formaction',
    'formenctype',
    'formmethod',
    'formnovalidate',
    'formtarget',
    'name',
    'type',
    'value'
],
GLOBAL_ATTRS: [
    'accesskey',
    // 'class',
    // Note: React specific, all needs to be lower case
    'classname',
    'contenteditable',
    'contextmenu',
    // 'data-*', needs to test specifically
    // Note: React specific
    'dangerouslysetinnerhtml',
    'dir',
    'draggable',
    'dropzone',
    'hidden',
    'id',
    'itemid ',
    'itemprop ',
    'itemref',
    'itemscope',
    'itemtype',
    'lang',
    'slot',
    'spellcheck',
    'style',
    'tabindex',
    'title',
    'translate'
],
EVENT_ATTRS: [
    'onabort',
    'onautocomplete',
    'onautocompleteerror',
    'onblur',
    'oncancel',
    'oncanplay',
    'oncanplaythrough',
    'onchange',
    'onclick',
    'onclose',
    'oncontextmenu',
    'oncuechange',
    'ondblclick',
    'ondrag',
    'ondragend',
    'ondragenter',
    'ondragexit',
    'ondragleave',
    'ondragover',
    'ondragstart',
    'ondrop',
    'ondurationchange',
    'onemptied',
    'onended',
    'onerror',
    'onfocus',
    'oninput',
    'oninvalid',
    'onkeydown',
    'onkeypress',
    'onkeyup',
    'onload',
    'onloadeddata',
    'onloadedmetadata',
    'onloadstart',
    'onmousedown',
    'onmouseenter',
    'onmouseleave',
    'onmousemove',
    'onmouseout',
    'onmouseover',
    'onmouseup',
    'onmousewheel',
    'onpause',
    'onplay',
    'onplaying',
    'onprogress',
    'onratechange',
    'onreset',
    'onresize',
    'onscroll',
    'onseeked',
    'onseeking',
    'onselect',
    'onshow',
    'onsort',
    'onstalled',
    'onsubmit',
    'onsuspend',
    'ontimeupdate',
    'ontoggle',
    'onvolumechange',
    'onwaiting'
]
```

And then, use the following method to check:

```
_.forEach(props, (value, key) => {
    // test data-*
    if (/^data-\w*$/i.test(key) ||
        // for valid key
        htmlConstants.VALID_BUTTON_ATTRS.indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
        htmlConstants.GLOBAL_ATTRS.indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
        htmlConstants.EVENT_ATTRS.indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        validAttrs[key] = value;
    }
});
```